# what is this C++ define doing? how can I write it in Python?

Tags: c++, python

I have this C++ define

```
#define CSYNC_VERSION_INT(a, b, c) ((a) << 16 | (b) << 8 | (c))
```

I need to define the same in Python. What is this doing? How can I do the same in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent would be

```
def CSYNC_VERSION_INT(a, b, c):
    return a << 16 | b << 8 | c
```

It byteshifts `a` left by 16 bits, `b` left by 8 and `c` intact; then all these numbers are bitwise orred together. It thus packs the `a, b, c` into three (four) bytes of an integer, so that the lowest byte is the value of `c`, the second lowest is `b` and the topmost bytes are the `a` value.

`CSYNC_VERSION_INT(3, 2, 8)` is equal to 0x30208 in hex, or 197128 in decimal.

Comment: It packs three subcomponent of e.g. a version id into a single number.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add to Antti Haapala's answer what that macro does: it creates an int from three bytes, which are a, b and c.

Example:

```
int main()
{
     unsigned int a = 0x02;
     unsigned int b = 0xf4;
     unsigned int c = 0x56;
     unsigned int p = CSYNC_VERSION_INT(a, b, c);
     // now p == 0x02f456
}
```

Comment: This might be useful if a, b, and c were 8-bit bitfields (where each bit is used as a flag).  This would "concatenate" those bitfields into a single 24-bit bitfield.

Comment: Technically, a doesn't have to be a byte.  It can be a short (2 bytes).  If a, b, or c are outside the range for a short, or bytes (respectively), the macro will overflow and the expected result will not be anything close to the actual result.

Answer (score 1):

It is using bit-shifts to store a version number in a single `int`.  It will store the "major" version in the upper 16 bits, the "minor" version in the first 8 bits of the lower 16, and the "revision" number in the lowest 8 bits.

It will not work well if the inputs are too large (e.g. if a is outside the valid range for an unsigned short, or if b or c are outside the range of an unsigned char).  Since it has no type-safety, a better approach would be to make an inline function that does the same operation with the appropriate types:

```
inline unsigned long MakeVersion(unsigned short major, unsigned char minor, unsigned char revision)
{
    unsigned long l = (static_cast<unsigned long>(major) << 16) | (static_cast<unsigned long>(minor) << 8) | (static_cast<unsigned long>(revision);
    return l;
}
```

Since Python is a C-derived language, you should be able to use the same bit-shifts to accomplish the same task.

Answer (score 1):

You can write this in python with the same meaning

```
res = ((a) << 16 | (b) << 8 | (c))
```

Assuming you have 1B data type (like char) and you want to store all the data in bigger data type (>= 3B), you have use this shift, so for

```
a = 01001110
b = 11010001
c = 00100011
```

will be

```
res= 01001110 11010001 00100011
```

(dump, all in binary)

```
'<<' this means bitwise shift (left)
'|' this means bitwise or (logic or for every bit)
```

You can also use the opposite attitude, to make a, b, c from res

```
a = (res >> 16) & 0xFF
b = (res >> 8) & 0xFF
c = res & 0xFF
```

So shift out what you need and then select only the last byte and store it.
Very useful when making calculator with unlimited precision :)